# VB.NET open a Text File within the same folder as my Forms without writing Full Path

Tags: vb.net

I found a similar question but it was 5 years 8 months old, had 2 replies and neither worked for me ([VB.Net Read txt file from current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291345/vb-net-read-txt-file-from-current-directory))

My issue is that when I use the following code:

```
 Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Username_And_Password_Raw.txt")
    Dim usernameAndPassword = Split(fileReader, ",")
```

I get an error saying:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\wubsy\source\repos\NEA Stock Page System\NEA Stock Page System\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Username_And_Password_Raw.txt'.'

I have tried using all the different Applications.*BLANK*Path options I can find (ie; StartupPath, CommonAppDataPath, etc.) and they all return essentially the same error only with a different location.

[This is the folder layout of my TXT File - I know it's a terrible, incredibly insecure and generally awful way of storing login information but this is just for a NEA so will never ever actually be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWNOU.png)

This is the actual path of the TXT File if it helps

> C:\Users\wubsy\source\repos\NEA Stock Page System\NEA Stock Page System\Username_And_Password_Raw.txt

Answer (score 0):

The startup path is where your exe is located. That and all supporting files get copied to a binary directory when you compile in visual studio, in your case

> C:\Users\wubsy\source\repos\NEA Stock Page System\NEA Stock Page System\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows

But what you're trying to do, reference the file where it sits in your solution, is probably not the best way to do it, and your code above will work (with a change, will mention later) if you change the properties of the file in the solution.

Right click on the file in the Solution Explorer `Username_And_Password_Raw.txt`, select Properties. Modify `Copy to Output Directory` to either `Copy always` / `Copy if newer`, depending on your requirement. Now that file will copy to the same directory your exe is in, and the code above should work.

Note, when creating a path, don't use string concatenation because you may have too many or too few `\`; use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0):

```vb
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Username_And_Password_Raw.txt"
Dim fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
```

Comment: [There is a limit to the number of characters some versions of windows can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)